# Why does GSON produce different JSON for enum at custom TypeAdapter?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I wrote a `TypeAdapter` for a class that contains an enum attribute. This is the `write` method, which uses standard GSON serialization for the enum value:

```
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, MyClass object) throws IOException {
        if (object == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("type").value(gson.toJson(object.getType())); //this is the enum
        writer.endObject();
    }
```

When using this `TypeAdapter`, the produced JSON contains this part for the enum:

```
"type":"\"ENUM_VALUE\""
```

But when I use `gson.toJson(object)` on a class which contains this enum without a TypeAdapter, it produces:

```
"type":"ENUM_VALUE"
```

All `Gson` objects use the standard configuration. It produces the same result in the first version, whether I test the `TypeAdapter` directly or use a `Gson` and registering it.

Why is there a difference? I guess escaping is not needed here, so I’d like to avoid it.
Interestingly, deserialization works for both serialized versions with the `TypeAdapter` (with `gson.fromJson(reader.nextString())`).

I guess that the problem might occure because `gson.toJson(object.getType())` already produces quotes: `"ENUM_VALUE"` and when adding them to the `JsonWriter` with `writer.value(gson.toJson(object.getType())` it gets escaped. But how to handle this correctly, like GSON does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply your `TypeAdapter` is wrong. Replace it with:

```
public void write(JsonWriter writer, MyClass object) throws IOException {
    if (object == null) {
        writer.nullValue();
        return;
    }
    writer.beginObject();
    writer.name("type").value(object.getType().toString()); //this is the enum
    writer.endObject();
}
```

In your code, you create a string from the enum doing a JSON serialization. This produces `"ENUM_VALUE"` (`gson.toJson(object.getType())`), and then it is serialized again into a string so the result is `\"ENUM_VALUE\"`.

In my code, I get the string representation of the enum using the `toString()` method so no additional quotes are created.